# как реализовать реакцию бота на "/" в библиотеке Telegram.Bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram

[image: Скриншот]

Как реализовать в программе при вводе пользователя символа "/" всплывающее окно со всеми доступными командами?

Суть в том, когда пользователь в чате telegram вводит символ "/" , появляется окно со списком доступных команд, из которых пользователь может выбрать необходимую.

Comment: недостаточно описал. Суть в том, когда пользователь в чате telegram вводит символ "/" , появляется окно со списком доступных команд, из которых пользователь может выбрать необходимую.

Answer (score 5):

Делается просто: 
Отправляем команду /setcommands пользователю @BotFather выбираем нашего бота, вводим команды и описание.

Никаких действий в языках программирования делать не нужно.